# drake::PackageMap ignoring paths?

Tags: drake

PackageMap ignores the newly found paths and has an unclear PackageMap warning.

I keep getting this warning about drake::PackageMap -

> WARNING:drake:PackageMap is ignoring newly-found path
> "external/drake/" for package "drake" and will continue using the
> previously-known path at
> "/home/arrowhead/.cache/bazel/_bazel_arrowhead/c61277c3c16dfdb5495d3775a1346bed/execroot/outdoorSLAM/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/planning/teleop/punito.runfiles/drake".

Not sure what to take from it -- as in not clear why it's ignoring the newly-found path?  Is there a recommended way to go about it that I am missing? Link to [repro](https://github.com/Zhourobotics/outdoor_slam_ros2/tree/main/planning/teleop) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the repro, I see `parser.package_map().PopulateFromFolder(".")`.  That's somewhat surprising!  Is `"."` always the right answer in that case?

I'll bet that sometimes "." is not what you think it is.  If your current working directory is anything other than your `/path/to/outdoor_slam_ros2/planning/teleop`, you'll be searching through lot of files that you don't need (e.g., maybe everything in your whole source tree, including `bazel-out` temporary files?).

More robust would be something like this:

```
parser.package_map().AddPackageXml(f"{something}/planning/teleop/data/package.xml")
```

where you've set `something` to be your source tree root.  That would either do exactly what you want, or give you a "file not found" error if there is any mistake.

Another way would be `parser.package_map().PopulateFromRosPackagePath()` which would load your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable.